# django multi level many to one query data retrieve

Tags: python, django

I have bit complex database model structure, see below(only the structure)

```
class Service(models.Model)
    fields .....

class ServiceBillPost(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name='service_bill_posts')

class Payment(models.Model):
    bill_post = models.OneToOneField(ServiceBillPost)
    mode = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=PAYMENT_MODE, default=0)

PAYMENT_MODE = (
(0, 'Cash'),
(1, 'bKash'),
(2, 'CreditCard'),
(3, 'Cheque'),
(4, 'Company'),
)
```

now i want to fetch , all `ServiceBillPost` of a `Service` which `payment mode` is `company`.

i have `service_id`, say 1,

then i have get that service,

```
 service = Service.objects.get(pk=service_id)
```

then get all the service bill post,

```
service_bill_post = service.service_bill_post.all()
```

but here how can i filter by `payment mode` of `mode` field of `Payment` model according to the above given relationship using django ORM?

Comment: How are `Service` and `Payment` connected? Is there anything in `Service` pointing to `Payment` or only backwards?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?:

```
service_bill_post = service.service_bill_post.filter(payment__mode='Cash')
```

*Assuming:

`bill_post = models.OneToOneField(ServiceBillPost, related_name='payment')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()`:

```
service = Service.objects.get(pk=service_id)
service_bill_posts = service.service_bill_posts.filter(payment__mode='Company')
```